# Android studio 1.4 Library module with JNI

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create an android module with JNI in android studio, but all the documentation I found is for older versions of android studio that did not officially support JNI. So, what is the correct way to create Library module with JNI in Android studio 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly same as with `'com.android.model.application'`. Everything seems to work fine except that for me, native debugging required running NDK build steps in the **app** module.